# Subversion SVN: Repository has been moved Repository moved permanently to XXX please relocate

Tags: svn, relocation

I dont understand SVN right now. When I change a file and try to update, it gives me the following error:

```
Repository has been moved
Repository moved permanently to 'http://myIpAdress/svn/'; please relocate
```

As far As I know I didnt change the adress of my repository or anything. The other clients have the same error, so there seems to be something wrong with the repository, and not the svn client. Any suggestions? The adress of my repository is "/var/svn/repository", this is the Location-tag inside my Apache-Config:

```
<Location /svn>
 SVNPath /var/svn/repository
.... other tags
</Location>
```

And this is the structure of my repository:

```
repository->myWebapp->Trunk
```

**UPDATE:**

The svn info command inside my working copy gives me the following results:

```
URL: http://myIpAdress/svn/myWebApp/trunk
Repository Root: http://myIpAdress/svn
```

Answer (score 3):

Try issuing the command `svn info` and look at the repository path.  I suspect that it doesn't match the http://myIpAddress/svn/ value you quoted above.

If it doesn't match, you should use `svn switch --relocate URL_FROM_SVN_INFO http://myIpAddress/svn/`

Comment: If your Subversion services are being fronted by Apache, check your httpd.conf setup.  Something is not allowing the IP address to resolve correctly to the Subversion repository it should be connecting to.  But in any case, you should be using the DNS name and not an ip address to checkout working copies.